# Is there a good way to handle exceptions in MVC ChildActions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, child-actions

I seem to be doing a lot of Exception swallowing with Child Actions.

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    [OutputCache(Duration = 1200, VaryByParam = "key;param")]
    public ActionResult ChildPart(int key, string param)
    {
        try
        {
            var model = DoRiskyExceptionProneThing(key, param)
            return View("_ChildPart", model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log to elmah using a helper method
            ErrorLog.LogError(ex, "Child Action Error ");

            // return a pretty bit of HTML to avoid a whitescreen of death on the client
            return View("_ChildActionOnlyError");
        }
    }
```

I feel like I'm cutting and pasting heaps of code, and with each cut an paste we all know a kitten is being drowned in angels tears.

Is there a better way to manage exceptions in child actions that would allow the rest of the screen to render appropriately?

Comment: What kind of exception are you catching here?

Comment: Any Exception, I've inherited some pretty ugly code. The problem is if exceptions aren't caught in child actions the whole screen doesn't render. I am able to keep the thing running this way and gather evidence as to what is throwing the exception. Most of the exceptions seems to be data missing and that kind of thing.

Comment: I'd consider doing these in a custom Action Filter that could be shared with all of your actions.

Comment: so how do I wrap my action method logic in an Action Filter?

Comment: Rvan's answer uses one type of Action Filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a CustomHandleError attribute based on Mvc's HandleError attribute, override the OnException method, do your logging and possibly return a custom view.

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    // Log to elmah using a helper method
    ErrorLog.LogError(filterContext.Exception, "Oh no!");

    var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
    var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];

    if (!filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
    {
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "_ChildActionOnlyError",
            MasterName = Master,
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model),
            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
        };
        return;
    }
}
```

Then decorate any controllers and/or actions that you want to enable with this logic like so:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
[OutputCache(Duration = 1200, VaryByParam = "key;param")]
[CustomHandleError]
public ActionResult ChildPart(int key, string param)
{
    var model = DoRiskyExceptionProneThing(key, param)
    return View("_ChildPart", model);
}
```

Comment: what is this line 'filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled' checking?

Comment: If you have custom errors RemoteOnly (and you visit the application locally) or Off then this property is set to false. This prevents the display of sensitive information to the public.